# For which (concrete) categories does the following hold: the subcatgeory whose objects are finite has a set-wise of objects?

Tags: category-theory, set-theory

I was thinking about how to prove that certain classes of "sets with structure" (Groups, Rings, Topological spaces ...) are proper classes and not sets.

Once one notices that the collection of all finite sets is a proper class, one has a machinery to prove that any concrete category where finite sets are automatically objects will have a proper class of objects.

This for instance holds in the case of Metric Spaces and Topological Spaces, but what can we say about this problem in general?

Comment: Once you care about the structure, rather than the set, then you're done. There is a proper class of pairwise disjoint sets of any non-zero cardinality. Simply consider $\{A\times\{x\}\mid x\in V\}$, where $A$ is your set of a given cardinality. This has nothing to do with finite, and everything to do with caring about structure rather than sets.

Comment: But, the *skeleton* of the category of finite whatever structures always has a set of objects.

Comment: @Berci Do you have something specific in mind when you say "whatever structures" ? What you say doesn't seem to be true for every concrete category.

Comment: @Arnaud: Upto isomorphism there are at most finitely many structures of size $n$ in a finite signature...

Comment: @AsafKaragila Of course, but it's not clear to me whether "whatever structures" should be understood as something defined by a signature, or if it also includes other things, like a metric or a topology...

Comment: @Arnaud: In the finite case you can code all these things into a finite first order language...

Comment: @AsafKaragila, thanks!  So just to be sure I am getting it: given, for instance any group $G$ I can always consider a "V-wise" class of distinct copies of $G$ which are $\{G\times\{x\}|x\in V\}$ and any of it will "trivially" inherit the group structure of $G$.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.